# Incorrect syntax near 'ID'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssms

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    cn = New SqlConnection
    cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=LAPTOP-VLPOS8UG;Initial Catalog=FAMS;Integrated Security=True"
    Try
        cn.Open()
        Dim query As String
        query = "INSERT INTO Master (Asset ID, Asset Category, Department, Brand/Make, Product Serial No, Purchase Date, Purchase Order Date, Installation Date, Purchase Cost, Depriciation Rate, Vendor Code, Warranty Details, Processor, RAM, HDD, Operating System, Application/Software, Note, Asset Name, Status)" + "VALUES ('" & Asset_IDTextBox.Text & "','" & Asset_CategoryComboBox.Text & "','" & DepartmentComboBox.Text & "','" & Brand_MakeTextBox.Text & "','" & Product_Serial_NoTextBox.Text & "','" & Purchase_DateDateTimePicker.Text & "','" & Purchase_Order_DateDateTimePicker.Text & "','" & Installation_DateDateTimePicker.Text & "','" & Purchase_CostTextBox.Text & "','" & Depriciation_RateTextBox.Text & "','" & Vendor_CodeComboBox.Text & "','" & Warranty_DetailsComboBox.Text & "','" & ProcessorComboBox.Text & "','" & RAMComboBox.Text & "','" & HDDComboBox.Text & "','" & Operating_SystemComboBox.Text & "','" & Application_SodtwareTextBox.Text & "','" & NoteTextBox.Text & "','" & Asset_NameTextBox.Text & "','" & StatusComboBox.Text & "')"
        cmd = New SqlCommand(query, cn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        MessageBox.Show("Data Saved")
        cn.Close()
    Catch ex As SqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        cn.Dispose()

    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Rajsinh Jadhavrao, welcome to [so]. What programming language is this? Please tag your question with the language in use. To update your question, click on the **"[edit]"** link under the post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged your question with [ssms](/questions/tagged/ssms) I suppose your RDBMS is SQL Server.

Your table has spaces in several column names; try using square brackets around column names that contain spaces:

```
query = "INSERT INTO Master ([Asset ID], [Asset Category],...
```